# Datagridview mangling smallDatetime database field

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, gridview

I am populating a DataTable and then binding this to a GridView control.  However, one of the boundfields is a smallDateTime field and the data is being mangled on insertion to the Gridview, how do you overcome this?  I have set the boundfield to have formatting but to no avail the dates are still wrong.  When I say wrong I mean that, for example, a record contains the date 11/21/2010, in the gridview it is shown as 3/2/2011... how do I correct this?

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="PubDate" headertext="Last Ad Date" 
                SortExpression="PubDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" 
                HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Width="75px" HtmlEncode="false">
            </asp:boundfield>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you have access to the stored procedure/SQL that is returning this data you could cast that field to a **datetime** before returning it: `CAST(mySmallDateField AS datetime)`

Comment: It already is smalldatetime, the problem is that the process of writing it to the datatable converts it to a string, which I am trying to stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're formatting as Decimal, not SmallDateTime. See, e.g., http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/.

Comment: John, I swapped it to this but it's still erroneous: ApplyFormatInEditMode="True" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HTMLEncode="false"

Comment: and according to your link: d ShortDatePattern M/d/yyyy